# Weird Error in NSURLConnection on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsurlconnection

I am making an iPad application and using `NSURlConnection` to connect to one of my web services to retrieve some data from the server. I am calling the webservice in such a way that it retrieves 20 records each time.

Sometimes after 10-12 calls the NSURLConnection the `DidFailWithError` delegate will be called. The error log says:

```
 The Internet connection appears to be offline
```

I have a retry button there as well. I keep on retrying but it keeps on getting the same error and goes to `DidFailWithError`.

Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Here is the code I am using:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soap length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"get_all_user_groups" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soap dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSUrlConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: Is this on device or simulator?

Comment: Could you post some code? - ^ah thanks

Comment: you can check the code. above this code i have a NSString which has a Soap Webservice XML PAcket in it.

Comment: When you have made 10-12 calls, are you waiting each time for the previous call to finish? or do you just keep instantiating a new request & connection with the same delegate?

Comment: What is the time taken between each of these calls? besides, did you check in your web server access logs if the connection is effectively established or not?

Comment: yes The Previous Connection is completey Closed. I have verified that. and just right after the nsurlConnection initwith request call it goes directly to the didFailWithError with the above mentioned Error.

Comment: Is every time the URL different? if not, did you try to add a random extra parameter (ignored by the web service) in order to have a different url and prevent a possible issue due to caching?

Comment: Are you getting a memory warning at any point during all of this?